# how to set ...initialize multiple unit id in mopub ios sdk

Tags: ios, swift, mopub

### my code

```
let config = MPMoPubConfiguration.init(adUnitIdForAppInitialization:"ad_unit_id")
        config.loggingLevel = .none

        MoPub.sharedInstance().initializeSdk(with: config) {
            print("mopub now use!!")
        }
```

why onle one unitid input?
my app is use both banner and reward..
What should I enter? plz..help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialise multiple ads units in mopub you can do like this:

```
    let sdkConfigBanner = MPMoPubConfiguration(adUnitIdForAppInitialization:MOPUB_AD_BANNER)
    sdkConfigBanner.loggingLevel = .info
    MoPub.sharedInstance().initializeSdk(with: sdkConfigBanner, completion: nil)


    let sdkConfigReward = MPMoPubConfiguration(adUnitIdForAppInitialization:MOPUB_AD_REWARD)
    sdkConfigReward.loggingLevel = .info
    MoPub.sharedInstance().initializeSdk(with: sdkConfigReward, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Mopub guidelines, you only need to initialise one ad unit ID belonging to the app.

> Initialize once per app’s lifecycle, typically on app launch, using
> any valid ad unit ID that belongs to the specific app you’re
> initializing with MoPub.

You can do this by:

```swift
let sdkConfig = MPMoPubConfiguration(adUnitIdForAppInitialization: "YOUR_AD_UNIT")
sdkConfig.loggingLevel = .none
sdkConfig.allowLegitimateInterest = true

// Mopub Configuration
MoPub.sharedInstance().grantConsent()
MoPub.sharedInstance().allowLegitimateInterest = false
MoPub.sharedInstance().initializeSdk(with: sdkConfig, completion: nil)
```

Extract from [Motics Mopub Blog](https://motics.vivushub.com/blog/how-to-integrate-mopub-interstitial-ads-swift/11/).